# Is there a plane in which every three points have an orthocenter?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, formal-completions

The title sounds trivial but bear with me.

We know from elementary geometry that every **nondegenerate** triangle $ABC$ (ie. points $A, B, C$ are all distinct) has an orthocenter $H$, defined as the intersection between two altitudes from a vertex to the opposite side. Importantly and well known (but not obvious to a beginner to prove) is that all three altitudes concur at the same point.

However, an issue arises when we consider a **degenerate** triangle, one in which (say) $A$ lies on segment $BC$. Then, the altitudes are all parallel lines, and in the standard Euclidean plane, these lines do not intersect at all, rendering our pedestrian definition of an orthocenter useless and leaving $ABC$ without an orthocenter.

My question is, can we expand / redefine the plane such that every "triangle" $ABC$ (nondegenerate or degenerate) has an orthocenter $H$ in the expanded plane?

My first guess was the real projective plane $\mathbf{P}^2$, which (ignoring the details of the $\mathbb{R}^3$ manipulation) adds one point at infinity for every direction with angle in $[0, \pi)$, and two parallel lines intersect at the point at infinity corresponding to the direction of the lines. (a direction is the same as the opposite direction.) This construction works for now - if $P$ is a "finite" point whereas $Q$ a point at infinity, then the line $PQ$ is defined as the (Euclidean) line through $P$ running in the direction of $Q$.

However, this breaks the following lemma from conventional Euclidean geometry: If $H$ is the orthocenter of $ABC$ (degenerate or otherwise), then (by definition) $A$ is the orthocenter of $HBC$ (using properties of perpendicularity and collinearity). If we had two distinct prospective orthocenters $H_1$ and $H_2$ on segment $BC$, then each of $H_1BC$ and $H_2BC$ would have orthocenter $A$, the point at infinity corresponding to the direction parallel to line $BH_1H_2C$. Then using our lemma, triangles $ABC$ could have orthocenter either $H_1$ or $H_2$, contradicting our desire that every triple of points has a unique orthocenter. For a given segment $BC$, all degenerate triangles $ABC$ with $A$ on line $BC$ would have the same orthocenter! Evidently, we need our points at infinity to carry some information not just about direction but also affine displacement in the direction perpendicular to that direction.

Is there a version of our pedestrian Euclidean plane that can ensure every triple of points has a defined and unique orthocenter?

Comment: The problem with your reasoning is that the orthocenter exists because there is a unique line perpendicular to one side $AB$ that passes through the other vertex $C$. This, on the projective plane, is false. That is, the orthocenter would be poorly defined. 

I think a more interesting question is whether an orthocenter concept equivalent to that of the Eucledian plane could be defined in the projective plane.

But focusing more on your question, why do you think it is important to consider degenerate triangles?

Comment: Exactly, in the projective plane we fail to have uniqueness of perpendicular lines. Your suggestion is a slightly different direction which is also interesting to consider (ie. redefine orthocenter in the projective plane), but I want the "dual", if you will, of this problem (ie. redefine the projective plane to keep orthocenters). As for why, why complete any set at all? Why complete the rationals to get reals, the plane to get the projective plane, the Riemann int.able functions to get Lebesgue int.able functions? Maybe some cool plane will come out of it, maybe not.

Comment: Actually, thanks to your comment I realize there is something much more fundamental going on. In the projective plane, some combination of axiom 4 (all right angles are congruent) and 5 (the parallel postulate) become invalid when trying to construct a (supposedly unique) line through point P perpendicular to line BC when P is a point at infinity. Maybe in our new geometry we can do away with the parallel postulate, but for my question we need uniqueness of perpendiculars. Do projective analogues of spherical or hyperbolic geometry exist?

Comment: Before you made your comment, I was wondering if we could keep the usual projective geometry (ie. points have three coordinates and are taken modulo homothety through the origin), but instead of the three coordinates being real numbers (or complex numbers) we use dual numbers - the real component representing points and the "fermionic" / epsilon component representing infinitesimal directions or displacements. I was thinking this because if $BC$ is a finite segment and $A$ a point at infinity, then the feet of the altitudes from B and C would be C and B, but we'd need some way to

Comment: encode the ratio of the distance between B and the foot from C, and C and the foot from B. Let me keep thinking about this idea...

Comment: The answer to my question is no, precisely because thanks to duality in the projective plane, we only have "concurrency and collinearity" results. Anyway, according to your reasoning, to "have" orthocenter in the degenerate case, the infinite points must be included. That is, any plane you consider will have to contain the projective, where we saw that it is not possible.
In particular, it should be noted that the concept of orthocenter is closely linked to the concept of distance/projection.